# You did not specify an i18n translation domain for ... in your [genericsetupprofile registration] in Plone

Tags: plone, zope

On Plone start-up I am getting a warning from a custom product

```
/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/fields.py:416:
UserWarning: You did not specify an i18n translation domain for the 'title' field in /Users/mikko/code/xxx-dev/src/xxx-eggs/Products.xxxExternal/Products/xxxExternal/configure.zcml
```

However in `configure.zcml` there is `i18:domain` set. I also set it directly with some extra attributes just to be sure:

```xml
<configure  xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    i18n:domain="xxxPatient"
    >

  <include package=".browser" />
  <include package="plone.app.z3cform" />

    <!-- Register the installation GenericSetup extension profile -->
    <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="default"
      title="xxxExternal"
      directory="profiles/default"
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
      i18n:attributes="title; description"
      i18n:domain="xxxPatient"
      />


</configure>
```

This is the related code giving the warning:

```py
def fromUnicode(self, u):
    context = self.context
    domain = getattr(context, 'i18n_domain', '')
    if not domain:
        domain = 'untranslated'
        import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()
        warnings.warn(
            "You did not specify an i18n translation domain for the "\
            "'%s' field in %s" % (self.getName(), context.info.file )
            )
    v = super(MessageID, self).fromUnicode(u)
```

Any idea why i18n:domain is not coming along or how to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the code is looking for `i18n_domain` with an underscore, but you specified it as `i18n:domain`, a namespaced value, instead.

The following works:

```xml
<configure  xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    i18n_domain="xxxPatient"
    >

  <include package=".browser" />
  <include package="plone.app.z3cform" />

    <!-- Register the installation GenericSetup extension profile -->
    <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="default"
      title="xxxExternal"
      directory="profiles/default"
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
      />

</configure>
```

ZCML is not the same as ZPT when it comes to internationalisation. :-)

Comment: I thought i18n namespace some sort of standard what comes to XML localization.... why did ZCML creators wanted to do something so subtle different? This is pure evil.